# Create a one to many relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with arbitrary rows of books and one with specific rows of subjects and ids.

```
mysql> describe books;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| title | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


mysql> describe subjects;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| subjects | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to associate one book to many subject ids, is there any array type I can use so that one column in my books table contains an array of different subject ids?

Can I then do a query on the books table to see which books are related to one subject?

Comment: By default MySql doesn't have the [Array data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541175/is-there-any-array-data-type-in-mysql-like-in-postgresql).

Comment: if 1. a subject can be linked to many books 2. a book can be linked to many subjects => oh, it's time for a relationship book_subject table !

Comment: If it's indeed `one-to-many` case then `LEFT JOIN` *books* to *titles" them and use `GROUP_CONCAT` in your `GROUP BY` query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relationship, not a one-to-many relationship. (A book can have several subjects, and a subject can have several books.)

The normative pattern is to implement a third table to store the "relationship" between books and subjects.

As an example of a minimal relationship table:

```
CREATE TABLE books_subjects
( subjects_id  INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK, FK ref subjects(id)'
, books_id     INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK, FK ref books(id)'
, PRIMARY KEY (subjects_id, books_id)
);
```

For InnoDB, we can define the foreign key constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE books_subjects ADD CONSTRAINT FK_books_subjects_books
  FOREIGN KEY (books_id) REFERENCES books(id);

ALTER TABLE books_subjects ADD CONSTRAINT FK_books_subjects_subjects
  FOREIGN KEY (subjects_id) REFERENCES subjects(id);
```

This effectively resolves the many-to-many relationship into two one-to-many relationships.

A `books` can have multiple `books_subjects`, but a `books_subjects` is related to exactly one `books`.

A `subjects` can have multiple `books_subjects`, but a `books_subjects` is related to exactly one `subjects`.

---

Queries to retrieve `books` related to a particular `subjects` would involve a JOIN operation to the `books_subjects` table.

For example, to find all `books` of particular `subjects`:

```
SELECT b.id
     , b.title
  FROM books b
  JOIN books_subjects j
    ON j.books_id = b.id
  JOIN subjects s
    ON s.id = j.subjects_id
 WHERE s.subjects = 'Psychology'
 ORDER BY b.title
```

To find `books` that don't have any `subjects`, e.g.

```
SELECT b.id
     , b.title
  FROM books b
  LEFT
  JOIN books_subjects j
    ON j.books_id = b.id
 WHERE j.books_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY b.title
```

---

NOTE: I typically use singular names for tables. So, there would be a lot fewer "s" characters in my column names and foreign key names. I may have omitted an "s" or two in my typing.

Comment: So if I have 100K books and 12K subjects, does that mean I may have a multi-million row table?

Comment: If every **`books`** is associated with every **`subjects`**, then you'd have 100,000 x 12,000 = 120,000,000 rows in **`books_subjects`**.  If each of the 100K `books` is related to an average of five **`subjects`**, then you'd have 500,000 rows in **`books_subjects`**.